# How to fill up the swap space quickly

Tags: swap

so I have a program that somehow can fill up the pagefile in Linux (2tb) instantly.  The problem is, it runs in Windows and I've tried wine with Linux and I can't get it to run.  I have made a tmpfs system in Linux, and used the cp command to copy all the files to the tmpfs file system.  However, this does not fill up the swap space quickly.. Is there any way that the space could be filled up faster, or somehow instantly??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to fill the swap space in the first place? Security reasons?

Comment: Wine can't throw low-level administrative calls. Like @wjandrea said, why??

Comment: I think that you're confused about what swap space/swap partition is used for? Please tell me what you think it's used for. Cheers, Al

Comment: Is It possible to fill up all of the memory space on a hard drive without actually writing to the disk?  I am trying to create as many instances of an image file as I can, but they have to be created instantly so I can't write any information to the disk.... I tried copying files into a swap partition but it was just as slow as a regular copy